# Limit pagination Laravel 4 when page not exist

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-4

i have this code:

```
    public function test(){
    $results = Cand::paginate(4);

    if (Request::ajax()) {
         return Response::json(View::make('admin.posts')->with('results', $results)->render());
    }

    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard')->with('results', $results);
 }
```

It works fine, but when a user enters a page that does not exist in the URL, like "?page=9999", how can I restrict this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the last page by calling `getLastPage()` on your paginator instance:

```
if ( Input::get('page', 1) > $results->getLastPage() )
{
    App::abort(404);
}
```